# Monitor.TryEnter always returns true even just after Monitor.Enter

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization

I think I am missing something about correct behaviour of `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.TryEnter`. Here is a piece of code I wrote to separate the issue from the rest of the code:

```
object lockObj = new object();
bool result = Monitor.TryEnter(lockObj);
Console.Write(result);
```

Result is always `true`. No surprises here.

```
object lockObj = new object();
Monitor.Enter(lockObj);
bool result = Monitor.TryEnter(lockObj);
Console.Write(result);
```

But this time it is also `true`. So is `lockObj` locked after `Monitor.Enter` or not? Please give me some fresh look at this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you are doing this in the same thread.

Also keep in mind that ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx)):

> It is legal for the same thread to invoke Enter more than once
>   without it blocking; however, an equal number of Exit calls must be
>   invoked before other threads waiting on the object will unblock

Comment: You are right. I think that `Monitor.TryEnter`'s [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw) should be a little bit more explicit about that.

Answer (score 0):

The same thread that has already acquired a monitor is always allow to reaquire it (to allow for re-enterant code).