# C# Monitor weird behavior

Tags: c#, synchronization, thread-safety, monitor

Maybe you can tell me what I'm doing wrong here:
I have a sync object, and I'm using `Monitor.TryEnter` in order to acquire the lock on that object, but then when I'm trying to acquire it again (using `Monitor.TryEnter`), I still manage to get it.
sample:

```
public class SafeDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, IXmlSerializable
{
    private readonly object syncRoot = new object();
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> myDict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    private const int monitorEnterTimeout = 5000;       // Timeout for Monitor (5 sec)
    private string dictionaryTitle;



    /* CODE */
    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        bool isLockTaken = false;

        try
        {
            // Acquire the lock:
            Monitor.TryEnter(syncRoot, monitorEnterTimeout, ref isLockTaken);
            if (!isLockTaken)
            {
                Log(@"Failed to Enter a monitor.");
                return;
            }

            // Add to the dictionary:
            myDict.Add(key, value);
            Backup(); // We haven't released the lock yet!
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Log(String.Format("Error adding to the dictionary: {0}", ex.ToString()));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (isLockTaken)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(syncRoot);
            }
        }
    }
    private void backup()
    {
        XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));
        bool isLockTaken = false;
       /* CODE... */

        try
        {
            // #####  We should not be able to take the key and enter the monitor:
            Monitor.TryEnter(syncRoot, monitorEnterTimeout, ref isLockTaken);
            if (!isLockTaken)
            {
                Log(@"Failed to Enter a monitor.");
                return;
            }
            // #####  YET we arrive here with isLockTaken = true
            /* CODE */
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Log(String.Format("Error Serializing the dictionary: {0}", ex.ToString()));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (isLockTaken)    
            {
                Monitor.Exit(syncRoot);
            }
        }
    }
```

I also try using the "immediate window" of the debugger and try to re-enter the Monitor section (after resetting the boolean), and I succeed every time. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are doing this on [more than one thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154401/monitor-tryenter-always-returns-true-even-just-after-monitor-enter)

Comment: Monitors and synchronization in general is done on `Thread` level. As long as you stay in the same `Thread` which already acquired the lock, no locking statement on the same object will effect the execution.

Comment: Okay, I did not know that information.
Thanks for both of you, solved

Comment: @WeSt - yes. And it's called re-entrancy and it's going out of fashion.